# Send variable to view without passing two instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to get a the number of children that meet certain criteria (is_confirmed, in this instance.) This is returned in `get_confirmed_amount`:

```
def get_confirmed_amount(reservations)
  amount = 0
  reservations.each do |reservation|
    if reservation.is_confirmed
      reservation.persons.each do
        amount = amount + 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I then calling this from the index action:

```
def index
  @reservations = Reservation.where(customer_id: session[:customer_id]).order(:name)
  confirmed_amount = get_confirmed_amount(@reservations)
end
```

I then need to pass this information to the view, but setting it as `@reservations.confirmed_amount` will return `NoMethodError`. How can I get the information to the view without having to send two instance variables to the view, or is that the only way?

Comment: fyi `get_confirmed_amount` isn't returning a count but `reservations`.  Instance variables and/or instance methods are the only way to send it to the view

Comment: The problem with `@reservations.confirmed_amount` is `@reservations` isn't a `Reservation` object. It's an `ActiveRecord Collection`. There may be a way to add a method to ActiveRecord Collections, but I don't know it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to set an instance variable?

Comment: @CameronAziz do you only need `confirmed_amount`?

Comment: You can `cut` the `get_confirmed_amount` method and then paste it to the `helper` file of the current `controller`. Then from view call for the method with `<%= get_confirmed_amount(@reservations) %>`

Answer (score 3):

As @okomikeruko has already said, setting an instance variable in the controller is the easiest way to access the data in the view.

If you really don't to do that for some reason, and assuming you also don't want to change your `#get_confirmed_amount` method (which I assume is a private method in your controller or else an included helper method), then you could create a helper method in your controller like this.

```
protected

def confirmed_amount
  return if @reservations.blank?

  get_confirmed_amount(@reservations)
end
helper_method :confirmed_amount
```

Another thing you could to, which would allow you to set confirmed_amount as a sort of property of the `@reservations` relation is this.

```
class ReservationsView < SimpleDelegator
  attr_accessor :confirmed_amount
end

# In your controller action
def index
  reservations = Reservation
    .where(customer_id: session[:customer_id])
    .order(:name)

  @reservations = ReservationsView.new(@reservations)
  @reservations.confirmed_amount = get_confirmed_amount(@reservations)
end
```

`SimpleDelegator` will pass all undefined methods to the `Reservation` `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, but will allow you to access the `confirmed_amount` value via a getter method. So in the view you can do this.

```
<%= @reservations.confirmed_amount %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `@` symbol sets it's global value within the action.

So:

```
@confirmed_amount = get_confirmed_amount(@reservations)
```

and

```
<%= @confirmed_amount %>
```

is how you would pass it along as its own variable.

Comment: if you're inferring global _scope_ then no.

Comment: Right. I'm not 100% versed in rails jargon, so I am most likely using the term _global_ wrong, but I do know without the `@`, it doesn't get passed to the view.

Comment: The confusion in terminology is entirely understandable. The way rails passes controller instance variables to views is not intuitive.